# Error in configuring JUnit in Jenkins: 'Tests/tests.xml' doesn’t match anything: even 'Tests' doesn't exist

Tags: jenkins, junit

I have created a freestyle project in Jenkins and I want to publish a JUnit result report after the build. The problem is that I don't know how to fill the field `Test report XMLs` because everytime I type the path of an xml file a red line appears saying

```
'Tests/tests.xml' doesn’t match anything: even 'Tests' doesn't exist
```

In reality the Tests folder exists and is inside Jenkins `workspace` folder and also the tests.xml file exists.

Comment: I have also tried to type "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Tests\tests.xml" but it insists saying that it does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

I have moved the Tests folder with its content to the MyProjectName folder that has automatically been created by Jenkins in the workspace. Because apparently the path is not relative to the workspace, but to the project folder that is contained in the workspace.